# Profile picture, whats the point, whats it used for?

Tags: user-profile

So I noticed I set a profile picture in Ubuntu.  There seems to be no point of it other than an extremely small icon about 4px by 4px when clicking at the top right.  Its not like it shows up at the login like in windows either.  So is there some point to it that I'm just not seeing or understanding?

Comment: That depends on the display manager - GDM shows a profile pic at the login screen. Some other apps also use it, IIRC.

Comment: I'm running what Ubuntu 14.04 comes with so its Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old gnome panel used to show the user profile in the power off /reboot etc menu. Also, it may be used by login managers, but not lightdm as far as I know (which is default in your version of Ubuntu). It's more a legacy option than anything, but if you installed KDE or other DE it may show up.

If you're curious, your profile pictures is stored as a hidden file in your home, called `.face` (without any extension). You can open it with:

```
gnome-open ~/.face
```

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin and Empathy use it as the default avatar.